# Calculating Impulse Response from a Frequency Curve

Tags: python, filter, scipy, signal-processing, librosa

I am trying to build a filter which has a frequency response resembling the spectrogram of a given piece of audio. This will be used as the loss filter for a physical modeling synthesizer.

```py
import soundfile as sf
import scipy.signal as signal
import librosa as rosa
...

audio, rate = sf.read('/Users/.../PianoSound.wav')
spect = rosa.feature.melspectrogram(audio, sr=rate)
spect = np.mean(spect, axis=1)
pyplot.plot(spect)
pyplot.show()

freqs = rosa.core.mel_frequencies(fmax=rate)
freqs = freqs / rate

b = signal.firls(127, freqs, spect)
a = [1]
w, h = signal.freqz(b, a)

pyplot.plot(w, 20 * np.log10(abs(h)))
pyplot.show()
```

The first plot is of the input sound:
[image: first plot]
The second plot is the frequency response of the filter:
[image: second plot]
This filter has gain at the lowest frequencies and does not represent the frequencies of the input sound. This is undesirable because this loss filter is supposed to model the degradation of energy in a string, so any amount of gain prevents a natural decay of the sound. Am I using the firls function of scipy correctly?

Comment: It would be easier to compare the plots if you used the same scale in each.  What does the plot of `spect` look like when the y coordinate is `20*np.log10(spect)`?

Comment: Here is a plot of spect with the same scale: https://i.imgur.com/7XzzAcO.png The shape is comparable but the relative amount of gain at certain frequencies is quite different.

Comment: Where did you get this procedure from?  It seems very strange.